# How to make marshmallow raise AttributeErrors on serialization

Tags: python, marshmallow

How can I make marshmallow make raise an exception when data is missing attributes?

Consider the following example:

```
In [8]: import marshmallow

In [9]: class Foo(marshmallow.Schema):
   ...:     bar = marshmallow.fields.Str(required=True)
   ...:

In [10]: class Bar:
    ...:     pass
    ...:

In [11]: bar = Bar()

In [12]: Foo().dumps(bar)
Out[12]: MarshalResult(data='{}', errors={})

In [13]: bar.bar
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-6901e83d9f0c> in <module>()
----> 1 bar.bar

AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

What's even worse, is this:

```
In [14]: foo.loads(foo.dumps(bar).data)
Out[14]: UnmarshalResult(data={}, errors={'bar': ['Missing data for required field.']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following quote from this [issue](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/295#issuecomment-146745553) explains the behavior you're describing in the first part of your question.

> This is by design. Primarily for performance reasons, validation only
>   happens on deserialization (`load` and `validate`). The data passed to
>   `dump` is assumed to be valid.

The expectation is that you'll explicitly call `validate()`, if you need validation, e.g. from your example:

```
In [10]: foo.validate(foo.dump(foo).data)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-4dfb5988e928> in <module>()
----> 1 foo.validate(foo.dump(foo).data)

...

ValidationError: {'bar': ['Missing data for required field.']}
```

Regarding the lack of validation during deserialization, for the version of `marshmallow` that you're using you have to explicitly declare the schema to be 'strict' in order for validation to happen automatically. In your example, this can be accomplished with:

```
In [22]: class Foo(marshmallow.Schema):
    ...:     bar = marshmallow.fields.Str(required=True)
    ...:     class Meta:
    ...:         strict = True

In [23]: foo = Foo()

In [24]: foo.loads(foo.dumps(bar).data)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
ValidationError: {'bar': ['Missing data for required field.']}
```

As discussed in [Issue 598](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/598), this behavior was changed and the latest version of `marshamallow` defaults to this 'strict' behavior; it also removes the `MarshalResult`/`UnmarshalResult` wrappers.